# I was wondering how I would make an image appear when I hover over another image

Tags: html, css, image, displaytag

Hi there I was wondering how I would make an image appear when I hover over another one.

I have some code but it just isn't working I think it should be something like this;

CSS-

```
a bikeq 
{
    display: none;
}

a:hover bikeq {
    display: block;   
}
```

HTML-

```
<section class="r_img">
    <a href=""><img src="img/bike.png" class="bike"></a>
    <img src="bikeq_3.png" class="bikeq">
    </section>
```

I fell like I am doing something wrong with the html part but I don't know what else to do.

Any help will be great thanks,

Zack

Comment: You are trying to use the child combinator here – but that second image is not a child of the link. Use the adjacent sibling combinator instead.

Comment: Also You have omitted the preceding period (full stop) from the class name in your selector.

Comment: you can not do that with css since you are trying to change the element which is not the children of the trigger element. you have to use javascript.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/wDVUd/

Comment: does this work?
http://jsfiddle.net/ge7kr02f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the HTML you have provided is not possible, as the elements are sibling. You can "fake" this effect with the following code:

```
<section class="r_img">
    <a href=""><img src="img/bike.png" class="bike"></a>
    <img src="bikeq_3.png" class="bikeq">
</section>

.bikeq {
    display: none;
}

.r_img:hover .bikeq 
{
    display: block;   
}
```

When hovering the container of the two images, the image with .bikeq class will show up..

Comment: this solution works but I was wondering what you meant by fake if I am doing it a bad way? Also I was wondering if there is now a way to to other element reacting to the image appearing. As I am getting some images moving slightly. Also Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what do you mean reacting when image appearing? Have you looked into css animation?

Comment: the images just bump up ever so slightly on there own. What I have is a circle of images and in the middle I am wanting to make an other image appear when I hover over one. What you told me worked for the first one that I tried but is not working for the other ones. I have not touched css animation but I would like to someday lol

Comment: _“Keeping the HTML you have provided is not possible”_ – yes it is. _“as the elements are sibling”_ – exactly, and that why the adjacent _sibling_ combinator allows to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html

```
<section class="r_img">
    <a href="" class=”bike_img”></a>
</section>
```

css

```
a.bike_img { width: ?px; height: ?px; display: inline-block; background: url("img/bike.png"); }

a.bike_img:hover { background: url("img/bikeq_3.png"); }
```

Where `?px` are the width and height of your image. You will also need to make sure that your image urls are corrrect, I just had a guess.

Comment: Although I may have misinterpreted what you were after